# bash script для init.d

Tags: linux, bash, автозапуск

День добрый.
Линукс начал изучать не так давно, и возникли проблемы с реализацией автозапуска.
Имеется скрипт, который проверяет наличие SD, монтирует ее, запускает какое-то приложение (которое к примеру мониторит сеть и в целом не имеет самостоятельной точки выхода, только по сигналу).
После чего в процессах висят сам скрипт и запущенное приложение.

Хотелось бы теперь сделать так, чтобы скрипт запускался при старте системы. И соответственно выключался сам и выключал приложение при выключении системы. (ну и соответственно возможность включения/выключения самостоятельно).

Нашел такое решение:

1. Положить скрипт в init.d
2. Выполнить команду
   `update-rc.d script_name start 98 2 3 4 5 . stop 20 0 1 6 .`

Если я правильно понимаю, то при запуске будет вызываться `script_name start`, а при выключении `script_name stop`?
Подскажите пожалуйста, как должна теперь выглядеть структура скрипта для корректной работы?

Или достаточно будет чего-то подобного?:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -z "$1" ]                 # Проверка наличия входного аргумента.
then
        echo "Error! "
        exit 1
fi

programm_name="/home/user/programm";

case "$1" in
   start)
        #check & mount SD
        if [ $(pgrep $programm_name)>'0' ]
        then
            killall -9 $programm_name
        fi
        $programm_name
        ;;
   stop)
        #check & umount SD
        if [ $(pgrep $programm_name)>'0' ]
        then
            killall -9 $programm_name
        fi
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: а в сторону fstab не смотрел?

Comment: А он разве не только для монтирования устройств?

Comment: В общем то должно работать так, только настораживает "_После чего в процессах висят сам скрипт_". Скрипт запуска должен завершиться после того как запустит программу, иначе процесс загрузки системы дальше не пойдет. Так же можете посмотреть как оформлены другие скрипты запуска. В зависимости от дистрибутива и его версии у вас могут быть разные системы запуска, в которых вместо /bin/sh используется нечто другое, которое поставляет скрипту некоторые дополнительные проверки. И pgrep не принято использовать, все уважающие себя демоны используют pid файлы в /var/run

Comment: А учитывая, что вы все равно завершаете программу по -9 сигналу можно положить запуск программы куда нибудь в local.d (или соотв. скрипт в вашей системе) и про завершение вообще не думать, его и так прибьют при завершении системы, сначала 15, а потом уже и 9 сигналом

Comment: @Mike спасибо. Это я не учел. Значит запускать приложение надо не через "$programm_name" а так, чтобы оно отвязывалось от потока скрипта.   Система у меня ubuntu 14.10.  Про pid файл я как-то не подумал - подменю завершение.

Comment: @Mike , а вот насчет остановки я пока просто не придумал. Хотелось бы завершать приложение корректно, чтобы оно само сетевое соединение отключало корректным образом.  Но пока не разобрался - какой сигнал для этого лучше слать (SIGKILL и SIGSTOP вроде бы из программы не перехватываются ведь)

Comment: Можете запускать приложение с `&` что бы оно ушло в фон, правда это не меняет его потоки ввода-вывода и если оно что то попытается вывести в stdout/stderr то это либо выведется на консоль, либо оно может быть остановлено системой тем самым SIGSTOP. В идеале надо что бы приложение само корректно отвязалось от терминала, т.е. закрыло подменило STDIN/OUT/ERR. либо надо для надежности использовать nohup. А нормальное завершение программы - это 15 сигнал (SIGTERM)

Comment: @Mike т.е. запуск сделать вида "nohup $programm_name >/dev/null &"?    А завершение соответственно делать как "killall -15 $programm_name"?  Спасибо, сейчас попробую сделать. И решу вопрос с PID файлом.  Я правильно понимаю, что программа при закрытии сама должна править PID файл? или после kill -15 лучше проверять как-то и править его из скрипта?

Comment: да, типа того. кстати killall без указания сигнала именно 15 посылает. И возможно стоит его и не указывать, что бы точно был TERM принятый в вашей системе (хотя на данный момент во всех linux он 15)

Comment: @Mike Вроде реализовал, но в автозапуск не ставится. Пытался делать по мануалу http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/создание_скрипта_автозапуска  (2 пункт).  Скрипт закинул в init.d но команда на update-rc.d не работает

Comment: Что значит команда не работает, она какие то ошибки выдает ? по хорошему, все что делает эта команда - добавляет символические ссылки на скрипт из каталогов /etc/rcN.d с именем `S70myscript` для запуска и `K20myscript` для останова. (где 70 и 20 порядок старта/завершения)

Comment: @Mike а нет. Автозапуск вроде работает. Просто warning выдает - start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults

Comment: видимо какая то более новая версия. эти утилиты часто меняются. посмотрите man

Comment: @Mike а не подскажете - как сделать так, чтобы после выполнения скрипта - он свой путь добавил в общую переменную PATH. Чтобы скрипт можно было вызвать из любой директории.   Пробовал так: 

  MY_DIR=`readlink -f "$(dirname "$0")"`
export PATH=$PATH:$MY_DIR
Но ничего не получается. Скрипт он не видит из других папок

Comment: по идее это должно было сработать в случае если скрипт выполнялся в том же командном интерпретаторе из которого вы позже пытаетесь использовать этот путь. если это тот самый стартовый скрипт - то он для системы этого сделать не сможет т.к. интерпретаторы работающие у пользователей запускаются из других веток процессов нежели стартовые скрипты

Comment: Ну да, я заметил что из разных терминалов он export не видит. Пришлось руками в .bashrc прописать пути

Comment: Правильнее разбить скрипт на две части - основа, которая находится в путях, например, */usr/local/bin*, и обёртки для запуска в */etc/init.d*.

Comment: @0andriy  Просто продублировать скрипт? (Точнее ту часть, которая start/stop)

Comment: Нет, дублировать как раз ничего не надо. Основной скрипт как есть, так и остаётся со своим интерфейсом, местоположением на диске и т.п. Новый скрипт, размещаемый в */etc/init.d/*, является просто обёрткой вокруг.

Comment: есть классная штука `start-stop-daemon` и ещё более класная штука `systemd`. Вот в системд есть события на подключения флешки и сети можно программе поставить зависимости и она запустится когда нужно

Answer (score -1):

Если Вам нужно просто запустить некий процесс в фоне до логина первого пользователя. то просто впишите его в файл /etc/rc.local Этот скрипт выполняется ПОСЛЕ завершения подготовки ОС к работе. Только не забудьте поставить & после имени Вашего скрипта. Как-то так :

```
!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# Это запуск вашего скрипта:
my_script.sh &

exit 0
```

Comment: Ну в целом да, я думал про этот вариант. Но хотелось бы еще, чтобы и и при выключении скрипт отрабатывал ведь. Для корректного закрытия  каких-либо файлов

Comment: **при выключении скрипт отрабатывал** - ну тогда, либо Вы реализуете Вашу первоначальную идею с init.d, либо в ту программу, которая крутится в скрипте, ввести обработку SIGTERM. Смысл тут вот какой: когда система даунится, начальный процесс (init) рассылает ВСЕМ своим потомкам этот сигнал. Shell пропускает этот сигнал через себя в ту программу, которую он выполняет в данный момент. Если она примет этот сигнал и выполнит необходимые действия - всё будет ОК.

Comment: ага, реализовал. Но я же верно понял, что отсюда я могу запустить как "my_script.sh start &"  . Тогда у меня скрипт отработает по кейсу start. А при желании могу уже руками stop вызвать, в котором тоже SIGTERM отсылать (это когда надо самому выключить, до завершения системы) ?   тогда при выключении сигнал будет слаться от системы, а при вызове от скрипта?

Comment: **тогда при выключении сигнал будет слаться от системы, а при вызове от скрипта?** Я лично это не проверял, но по идее, так и должно быть.

Comment: /etc/rc.local - место для костылей.